# The series of $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{2})^{2j}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

The series converge:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2j}$$

I try to put it in geometric series but I am stuck some help please.

Comment: If you know how to sum a geometric series then the hint is $(\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: This is geometric series with $r=\dfrac14$ and the sum is
$$
\frac{1}{1-\frac14}=\frac43.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{2})^{2j}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{4})^{j}$$ which is a geometric series and converges because $\frac{1}{4} <1$.

Answer (score 1):

$(1/2)^{2j}=[(1/2)^2]^j$ should get you there...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(\frac12)^{2j}=(\frac14)^j$